# Variable for future income or future disposable income

Tags: macroeconomics

I am doing a project in macroeconomics. I need future disposable income data for the analysis which I couldn't find. Is there a variable/formula which captures future disposable income?

Comment: No - you would have to predict it, or take somebody else's predictions, presumably using macro- or microeconomic modelling depending on the context.

Comment: @Henry, Okay. Thank you